# PHP - MongoDB: Retrieve Fields from Sub Document with Field Names in Array

Tags: php, mongodb

Consider an Array

```
$lettersArray = [A,C,E,G]
```

and my MongoDB Collection has the following structure.

```
{
    Collection : {
        letters:{
            A:{...},
            B:{...},
            ...
            Z:{...}
        }

    }
}
```

Consider that the Letter Sub document is a part of a larger collection. Hence I am using Aggregation.
Right Now I have tried to project -

```
['$Collection.letters' => ['$elemMatch' => ['$in' => $lettersArray]]
```

and also tried

```
['Letters' => ['$in' => [$lettersArray,'$Collection.letters']]
```

But it didn't work.

In the End, I want result like the following:

```
 [
     Collection => [
        letters => [
            A => [...],
            C => [...],
            E => [...],
            G => [...]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can use array_combine with array_fill to create the empty arrays.

```
$lettersArray = ['A','C','E','G'];

$letters = array_combine($lettersArray, array_fill(0,count($lettersArray), []));
```

Array_fill creates an array from index 0, to the count of items in $lettersArray with the contents `[]`

Output:

```
array(4) {
  ["A"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["C"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["E"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["G"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/TeoFv

Comment: Hi $Andreas, Thanks for replying. This Question is actually MongoDB - PHP. I need to query such that I get the required result. The PHP functions won't work for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mistaken in the way you are trying to access the documents' information.

If you take a look at your MongoDB document, you will see that it is in fact not an array, so you should not use `$elemMatch` to project these fields, but simple projections. In your case, you should project in this way:

```
[
    '$project' => [
        'Collection.letters.A' => 1,
        'Collection.letters.C' => 1,
        'Collection.letters.E' => 1,
        'Collection.letters.G' => 1
    ]
]
```

By the way, you don't need to use the aggregation framework to compute such a projection. You could just use `find()`, and use the projection in the options, which are the functions' second argument:

```
myCollection->find(query, [
    'projection' => [
        'Collection.letters.A' => 1,
        'Collection.letters.C' => 1,
        'Collection.letters.E' => 1,
        'Collection.letters.G' => 1
    ]
]);
```

Cheers,

Charles

Comment: Thanks, Charles for replying, This is just a small example of a bigger issue. I cannot individually project since the array might increase to 20+ fields.  Thats true that I cannot use $elemMatch, I read about it. Is there any similar alternative for object